# Can model in MVC rollback to last valid state?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am following TornadoFX Guide from here, trying to run the sample wizard:
[Wizard](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Wizard.html)

I am having the following trouble, see item 3):

1) When I press `Cancel` the values are rolled back to empty values on 
  next open

2) When I press `Finish` the values are still in the wizard on next open

3) When I now press `Cancel` changes are not rolled back to 2) but to 
  1), i. e. empty fields

How do I get different `Cancel` behaviour: rolling back the CustomerModel to the last valid state?

This is my updated `CustomerWizard.kt`:

```
package com.example.demo.view

import com.example.demo.app.Customer
import com.example.demo.app.CustomerModel
import tornadofx.*
class CustomerWizard : Wizard("Create customer", "Provide customer information") {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val canGoNext = currentPageComplete
    override val canFinish = allPagesComplete

    override fun onCancel() {
        super.onCancel()
        customer.rollback()

    }

    override fun onSave() {
        super.onSave()
        customer.commit()

        println("customer.name=" + customer.name)
        println("customer.type=" + customer.type)
        println("customer.zip=" + customer.zip)
        println("customer.city=" + customer.city)
    }

    init {
        graphic = resources.imageview("/graphics/customer.png")
        add(BasicData::class)
        add(AddressInput::class)
    }
}

class BasicData : View("Basic Data") {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val complete = customer.valid(customer.name)

    override val root = form {
        fieldset(title) {
            field("Type") {
                combobox(customer.type, Customer.Type.values().toList())
            }
            field("Name") {
                textfield(customer.name).required()
            }
        }
    }
}

class AddressInput : View("Address") {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val complete = customer.valid(customer.zip, customer.city)

    override val root = form {
        fieldset(title) {
            field("Zip/City") {
                textfield(customer.zip) {
                    prefColumnCount = 5
                    required()
                }
                textfield(customer.city).required()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `CustomerModel.kt`:

```
package com.example.demo.app

import tornadofx.*

class CustomerModel(customer: Customer? = null) : ItemViewModel<Customer>(customer) {
    val name = bind(Customer::nameProperty, autocommit = true)
    val zip  = bind(Customer::zipProperty, autocommit = true)
    val city = bind(Customer::cityProperty, autocommit = true)
    val type = bind(Customer::typeProperty, autocommit = true)
}
```

This is my `MainView.kt`:

```
package com.example.demo.view

import com.example.demo.app.Customer
import com.example.demo.app.CustomerModel
import com.example.demo.app.Styles
import javafx.geometry.Pos
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import tornadofx.*

class MainView : View("Hello TornadoFX") {

    private val myCustomer: Customer? = Customer("test", 12345, "", Customer.Type.Private)
    override val root = drawer {
            item("Generate & sign", expanded = true) {
                button("Add Customer").action {
                    find<CustomerWizard>(Scope(CustomerModel(myCustomer))).openModal()
                }
            }
            item("Verify") {
                borderpane {
                    top = label("TOP") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.RED
                        }
                    }

                    bottom = label("BOTTOM") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.BLUE
                        }
                    }

                    left = label("LEFT") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.GREEN
                        }
                    }

                    right = label("RIGHT") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.PURPLE
                        }
                    }

                    center = label("CENTER") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER

                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.YELLOW
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            item("Sign next") {
                borderpane {
                    top = label("TOP") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.RED
                        }
                    }

                    bottom = label("BOTTOM") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.BLUE
                        }
                    }

                    left = label("LEFT") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.GREEN
                        }
                    }

                    right = label("RIGHT") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.PURPLE
                        }
                    }

                    center = label("CENTER") {
                        useMaxWidth = true
                        useMaxHeight = true
                        alignment = Pos.CENTER

                        style {
                            backgroundColor += Color.YELLOW
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //class Link(val name: String, val uri: String)
        //class Person(val name: String, val nick: String)

        // Sample data variables left out (iPhoneUserAgent, TornadoFXScreencastsURI, people and links)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `rollback()` on an `ItemViewModel`, it will roll back to the data found in the underlying `item`, or blank values if you never backed your `ItemViewModel` with an item.

In your case, that means you need to assign a `Customer` to the `item` property of your `CustomerModel`. After you have done that, you can call `rollback()` and the `CustomerModel` will show the state from the `Customer` it is backing.

If you get the same state when you reopen the Wizard, that means that you have reopened the exact same Wizard instance. A Wizard extends `View`, which makes it a singleton within it's scope, so if you just call `find()` to locate the Wizard without specifying a scope, the second attempt will get you the same instance as the first.

You didn't post your Wizard init code, but generally you should create a new scope for the Wizard if you want to avoid this. If you want the wizard to edit a specific customer instance, you should do:

```
val model = CustomermerModel()
model.item = myCustomer
find<CustomerWizard>(Scope(model).openModal()
```

It is for this reason normal to let the view model accept an instance in the constructor, which you pass on to the `ItemViewModel` constructor, so that the item is assigned for you automatically:

```
class CustomerModel(customer: Customer? = null) : ItemViewModel<Customer>(customer)
```

Not that I made sure to allow a no-args constructor for the CustomerModel, to support inject in cases where there is no CustomerModel in scope already. In that case a new CustomerModel (not supporting any customer item) will be created, so this situation requires a no-args constructor.

With that in place, the wizard init code becomes:

```
find<CustomerWizard>(Scope(CustomerModel(myCustomer)).openModal()
```

Hope this helps.